# Solution for android app bundle is signed with the wrong key problem for second time deployment after deploying first version successfully

Tags: flutter, deployment, stack-overflow

I have deployed first version of flutter app on google play console successfully, but when I try to upload again aab file using same jks file it is giving me - Your android app bundle is signed with the wrong key error. is there ant different method for creating aab file for second time in android studio?

I tried 2-3 method to generate aab file

1. generate signed bundle option from android studio
2. using terminal command for creating aab file

Answer (score 0):

You should need a same `key(jks/keystore)` file which you used to generate a `appbundle` to upload app in PlayStore. You may have to find a same key file to upload a build in PlayStore for update. Otherwise you may have to create a new app in PlayStore with new package name to upload your app. You can't use the same package name until you get the same key file which you used to upload previously.

Comment: Thanks for response , but after using same key I am getting this error.

Comment: I don't know what I am doing wrong for generating appbundle for second time.

Comment: When did you publish the app?

Comment: one month ago .

Comment: Is the key which you are using is created 1 month ago?

Comment: yes, and I store that file in one folder and later Using that key generate appbundle file.